# set proper constraint in bottom android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

Hey I am working on constraint layout in android. I am trying to fit my text view and image view in same row, and my image is bigger in size.

[image].

The problem is I want to give proper constraint. After setting the proper constraint it will look like this.

[image]

**activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/description"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="blah blah blah" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/testIcon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/testName"
        tools:text="blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/testIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image_pills"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/description"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/testName"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can someone guide me How to set proper constraint.

Answer (score 0):

in the first textview you need to make this changes:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/testIcon"
```

in the second textview you need to make this changes:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/testIcon"
```

in the imageview you need to remove this line:

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/description"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/testName"
```

Here is my sample working code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/dimen_12"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageview"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textView1"
    android:text="blah blah blah"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageview"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageview"
    android:text="blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I don't want textView to `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf` to imageView

Comment: then just set the constraint bottom property then